# initializer list in Clang

Tags: c++, c++11

Today Apple updates Command Line Tools for Xcode and then upgrades clang from 318.0.58 to 318.0.61.

I've tried to use initializer list, but can't compile below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <initializer_list>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng(time(NULL));

    std::initializer_list<double> probabilities =
    {
        0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1
    };

    std::discrete_distribution<> cheat_dice (probabilities);

    int a[6] = { };

    for ( int i = 0 ; i != 1000; ++i )
    {
        ++a[cheat_dice(rng)];
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i != 6; ++i )
    {
        std::cout << i + 1 << "=" << a[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Then, I tried to compile.

```
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ foo.cpp
```

Error log

```
foo.cpp:9:10: error: no member named 'initializer_list' in namespace 'std'
    std::initializer_list<double> probabilities =
    ~~~~~^
foo.cpp:9:33: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    std::initializer_list<double> probabilities =
                          ~~~~~~^
foo.cpp:9:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'probabilities'
    std::initializer_list<double> probabilities =
                                  ^
foo.cpp:10:5: error: expected expression
    {
    ^
foo.cpp:14:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'probabilities'
    std::discrete_distribution<> cheat_dice (probabilities);
                                             ^
5 errors generated.
```

On the other hand, I can compile above code with gcc-4.7.1-RC-20120606.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp
```

Doesn't Apple's clang support initializer list?
Clang version:

```
$ clang++ -v
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 14):

Try by specifying `-std=c++0x` (as @jweyrich correctly pointed out) as part of the `clang` command line. The default for `clang` is C++98 mode. Initializer lists are a C++11 feature.

Also, from the clang C++98 and C++11 [support page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) you can check the status of various new C++ standard features. For example, initializer lists are available in 3.1 (and above).

Comment: Apple's clang can't recognize `-std=c++11`

Comment: @user1214292: It recognizes `-std=c++0x` though.

Comment: @jweyrich But the result will be unchanged :(

Comment: @user1214292: as mentioned in the current answer, the Clang version (3.0) shipped by Apple does not support initializer lists.

Comment: @jweyrich
  $ clang++ -v  
  Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)  
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0  
  Thread model: posix

Comment: @user1214292: Oh, did Apple release an Xcode update after the keynote last morning? How did I miss that? Sorry for the off-topic discussion.

Comment: @jweyrich: It's the [Jun 11](http://appshopper.com/mac/developer-tools/xcode-3) update. However, the only note of interest I could find on the page was this: *Apple LLVM compiler supports C++11 features and the LLVM libc++ standard library*.

Comment: This was still an issue with clang 3.4, that flag fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

Compile using the command:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++0x foo.cpp
```

Note that `-std=c++11` also works. In my machine, running:

```
$ clang --version
```

results in:

```
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
```